# Image and Text arrangement in Gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to align Image and Text at center correctly, i tried several options if I get text aligned correctly then the image in circle changes to oval. If i make circle correct then text gets rendered.

```
Column buildItem(BuildContext context, String impagepath, String modulename) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,      
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: CustomButtonWidget(
                      image: impagepath,
                      size: 100,
                      borderWidth: 5,
                      onTap: () {
                        
                      },
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                
                child: Text(
                  "THIS IS BIG TEST WHICH",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.styleColor,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }  
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does work like you want but i don't have something to watch in your image code to give you an optimal solution.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myImageAndCaption = [
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "caption1"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "caption2"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "this is a big text"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "This is almost a bigger text"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "oh no this a really really big text"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "yes small one"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "yes"],
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            ...myImageAndCaption.map(
              (i) => Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Material(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      i.first,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      child: Text(i.last),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFOwn.png)
i hope it did help you good luck

Comment: Thanks Kadri, The result you showed is something similar my results are the problem is size of image changes and text change doesn't look good on UI. And i am trying to keep it identical for all.

Comment: I was able to make some changes in your code and that helped me resolve the issue. The updated answer so others can benefit from it..

Answer (score 1):

Posting my updated code, i was able to get circle and text aligned without any issue even with large text.

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        );
      ),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            ...myImageAndCaption.map(
              (i) => Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Material(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                    i.first,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                 ),
                    
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    
                    flex: 1,
                
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Text(i.last),
              ),
                    
                      ),
                                    
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]